Drupal Contribution Page How to Setting background Photo?
civicrm/admin/contribute?reset=1
How to set the background image in the input of each contribute page, I can't find any plugin that can do it.

Can you just add some css to your site's theme? e.g.
form.CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main { background: url(/images/bg.png) no-repeat; }

edit contribute page can be customized, to a custom upload image function, the image can be in their own contribute page as the background image, there are many contribute page, are able to use their own background image. There are many contribute pages that can use their own background images. Your method does not upload images.
